# Visual Studio 2022 Git Branch Manager Icons

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

In Visual Studio 2022, when I click on `Git > Manage Branches`, I get a list of branches. These branches have blue and green icons next to them. What do these mean?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was unable to find any documentation on these particular icons, but I believe the green up arrow icon denotes the branch has a remote tracking branch that can be pushed to.  See how this popup contains a "Tracked Branch" item:

[image: branch with a tracking reference]

For a branch that doesn't have a remote tracking branch, this icon doesn't appear and their is no "Tracked Branch" item in the popup:

[image: local branch]

Also, if I push this branch, the icon appears immediately after the `git push` completes since it now has a remote tracking reference. Likewise, if I right click the branch and "Unset Upstream Branch", the icon disappears.  I imagine if you delete the remote branch as well and [`prune`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch#Documentation/git-fetch.txt---prune) this icon would also disappear (it doesn't look like Visual Studio provides a way to do this though so you would have to use a command line or some other tool).

As for the blue icon with two arrows pointing inward, I believe that simply denotes that it is a remote/origin branch.

Comment: Thanks for your time. Maybe some day Microsoft will provide better documentation on this!